# xcode 5.1.1 data tips fails in debugging

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, debugging

Hover fails to display a value. There is no eye and info button. Clicking on the triangle next to a variable drops a menu that starts with Edit All In Scope.

After using Xcode 3.2.6 in OSX 10.6, I'm starting to use Xcode5 in OSX 10.9. It worked OK for a few weeks on new projects and downloaded examples, including data tips. Then a series of quirks associated with Custom View prevented its display. Breakpoints showed that drawRect was running. Only the main window appeared in Run. I found that in the Inspector, MyClass was not in the list of Classes.
Sometimes MyClass.h and .m file names appeared in red and the files were empty. Deleting Library>Developer>Xcode a couple times fixed these problems when they occurred, but only temporarily. Then I deleted Xcode.App and downloaded a new copy.

This seems to have taken care of all but the data tips problem. Projects do display the Custom View and its contents correctly, but data tips are absent.

How can I make it work correctly?

more information: I ran DiskWarrior and found no faults in Xcode and related files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For whatever reason, hover has started working again, after editing a few projects. I know not why.